# Algebra factor question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help me factor this equation?

(One hundred sixty)(one minus q divided by four)(ten plus q divided by 4)

Comment: Hi! Is the expression you wanted to write $160(\frac{1-q}4)(\frac{10+q}4)$? Because this expression is already factored... unless you want $10(1-q)(10+q)$ by putting the $4$'s below $160$.

Answer (score 1):

It would be *much* easier to be sure what you mean if you write the equation.  You could see [this from the faq](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto) or at least write 160(1-q/4)(10+q/4).  If you type in line, please make sure there are enough parenetheses to be unambiguous.  If you mean $160(1-\frac q4)(10+\frac q4)$ it is already factored in one sense.  What you probably want is first to multiply it out, giving $160(1-\frac q4)(10+\frac q4)=-10q^2-360q-1600=10(q-4)(q+40)$.  To find the factors, you can first factor our the $10$ by inspection, then try factors of 160 to find the roots (see [the rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem))

Comment: It seems like an odd thing to do to multiply it out and then factor it back in again... what are you trying to achieve that you couldn't just do directly?

Comment: @benmachine:  Right you are.  You can just do as Patrick Da Silva suggested (in another interpretation) and distribute the $4$'s in.